# Generic method of abstract class

Tags: java, generics

I've got the following method of an `public abstract class Model { //impl }` (declared exactly like this):

```
 protected <T extends Model> HashMap<String, Model> resultsetMap(ResultSet res) {
     HashMap<String, Model> data = new HashMap<String, Model>();
     try {
         while(res.next()) {
            Model obj = T.getNew(res);
            data.put(obj.toString(), obj);
         }
     } catch(SQLException e) {
         return null;
     }
     return data;
 }
```

1. `T` is supposed to tell the caller the concrete class it should use. Is this possible?
2. How would I call this method from another method of a subclass of `Model`? I've tried with `resultsetMap<Course>(res);` but it looks like a syntactic error

Comment: What do you mean by "is this possible?"  Did you try to compile it?

Comment: No I haven't, I'm an experienced programmer (yet not in java) and I wanted to get bashed for not already having a feeling for the language. If I don't get bashed, it means for me that I'm on the right path :D

Comment: Its a little bit off topic but I would recommend you to return a Map instead of HashMap. So you seperate the implementation and the interface. Then you can change the implemntation without changing the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the method is inherited, you can call it either as `super.<ConcModel>resultsetMap(/* arg */);` or `this.<ConcModel>resultsetMap(/* arg */);`. Second or first respectively based on whether the subclass is overriding it or not.

[Tutorial on how to call a generic method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html)

Comment: I was merely thinking about the "generic" part - how to tell it what `T` is?

Comment: For that you need to use, T as the method-parameter type.

Comment: Ok so how to specify the `T`? I don't know what a "method-parameter type" is, show me the syntax please.

Comment: I want to write this method only once in the base class `Model` and call it from another subclass `Foo` but it should generate me the list of another class `Bar` models. So in this sense, I don't think it actually maps to inheritance, but rather some kind of polymorphism.

Comment: Since, the type parameter `T` in `<T extends Model>` means something that is a subclass of `Model`. So, `Bar` has to be a subclass of `Model`.

Comment: Yep that's what I said, "another class `Bar` _models_". Thanks for the answer, it worked.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that part. But glad that it helped.

Comment: But it calls the method `Model.getNew()` and not `Bar.getNew()` (from within `Foo.resultsetMap()`, both `Foo` and `Bar` being subclasses of `Model`. :( How could I fix that? Is it possible only via reflection?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `T.getNew()` because the type of `T` is erased at runtime. You can pass in a Class object if you need to call Class methods.

In your code 'T' describes a type, it's not an instance of anything so you can't call methods on it. If it was an instance of an object you would need to pass it into the method anyway, if it's meant to be a static method it cant be overrided.

I would consider using the factory pattern, i.e. pass in a model factory to this method.

Comment: What if `getNew` is a method in `Model`?

Comment: Yes `getNew()` is a method of `Model` and it gets overwritten by those subclasses. Isn't that what `T extends Model` does?

Comment: You can call `T.getNew()` if that function is static, because `T` is erased to `Model`, so `T.getNew()` is the same as `Model.getNew()`. That said, the latter would be much more preferable style-wise.

Comment: @yshavit - but static methods can't be overridden.

Comment: @brain True -- that code probably doesn't do what the OP was hoping for. But it'll compile, and the result isn't even all that bizarre if you understand erasure.